# OPENROWSET vs BCP

Tags: sql-server-2008, export-to-excel, bcp, export-to-csv, openrowset

I need to export data from Sql Server 2008 to Excel/CSV file.

I have two options for that:

- OPENROWSET
- BCP

Which will be better options if amount of data is large and security is concern?

Comment: By BCP do you mean using a BULK INSERT statement, using the command line bcp tool, or using the sqlbulkcopy api?

Comment: Also depends what your security concerns are.  OPENROWSET is blocked by default and you'd need to enable with sp_configure before you could use it.

Comment: I mean BCP using xp_cmdshell. And both are blocked by default. And for security I mean for BCP we need Local System account to execute the command.

Comment: Just edited my answer.  I think bcp is the only way to go if performance is an issue at all.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good comments on a similar question here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=147861.

My leaning would be towards BULK INSERT, but really the best thing you can do is try it both ways.  Then you'll be able to compare which is faster and you'll have a better understanding of which will fit your security concerns better since you'll then know what security issues you had to address to make it work.

Edit: You are trying to export, so obviously BULK INSERT won't work.  BCP would be your more performant choice I believe, and besides I think it's your only choice if you want to do a bulk export.  I'm pretty sure OPENROWSET only allows for bulk imports into sql, but not exports.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?  I'm always open to learning my mistakes.

Comment: OPENROWSET works also for exporting data, and personally I like a lot this method: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1202/export-data-from-sql-server-to-excel/ ... but in this case you can't use it with CSV files, because it hasn't a "driver-driven" format